# Is the valid invalid bit a waste with respect to protection?

Tags: operating-system, paging

I am reading Operating system concepts . In memory protection the following example is given:

In a system with 14 bit address space we have a program that uses only addresses 0 to 10468 .The page size is 2 Kb .

Then they have showed a figure in which the page table contains 8 entries .

I don't understand why they have used 8 entries . The program needs only 6 entries.The first 6 entries are marked valid but the remaining two are marked invalid . But this is a waste of space . Why add the two entries only to mark it invalid .

Does this mean that the size of the page table is independent of how many page the process actually needs .

A better solution mentioned later says instead of adding all the entries the page table length register is used which stores the length of the page table .

But in the next chapter which explains about demand paging they again go back to this:
When demand paging is used , if a page is marked invalid then either it is not in the memory or it lies outside the logical address space (why add the page to the page table if it lies outside the logical address space ) .

A better solution is that the invalid bit should only mean that the page is not in memory  .

Please explain why the book is contradicting itself ?

Comment: Which book you are referring to?

Comment: Operating system concepts by Galvin and Silbershatz